# Jetpack WorkManager - organising WorkRequest

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I'm using Jetpack WorkManager to sync my database with the network. I have a lot of Workers.
It's not very nice to build every time requests like

```
val request = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<SampleWorker>()
    .setConstraints(networkContraints)
    .build()
```

before

```
workManager.enqueue(request)
```

Do you have any idea how to extract these request creation nicely?

I've checked google samples including Sunflower app, but haven't found well-organized one.

Answer (score 0):

I've made this, a simple Singleton where you declare your Worker and use it when in needs, there might be some optimisation to do.

```kotlin
object WorkerObject {

    fun syncDb(context: Context){

        val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context)
        val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build()

        val request = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<SampleWorker>()
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .build()

        workManager.enqueue(request)
    }

}
```

to call it:

```kotlin
WorkerObject.syncDb(application)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the inspiration @Biscuit. I've adjusted it to work with di and made it more generic to work with all my syncing workers.

```
class SyncManager(val context: Context) {

    inline fun <reified W : ListenableWorker> enqueue() {
        val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context)

        val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build()

        val request = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(W::class.java)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .build()

        workManager.enqueue(request)
    }
}
```

I'm invoking it like

```
syncManager.enqueue<UpdateUserWorker>()
```